# Ja klar, kann man machen

Tags: meaning

I asked someone the following:

> Willst du mit mir mal ins Kino?

The answer was:

> Ja klar, kann man machen.

What connotation does the answer carry?

Comment: "*What connotation does the answer carry?*" Not having *heard* the answer this is very difficult to answer.

Comment: Is it like the English version of it's fine?

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments.

Answer (score 4):

The German answer, translated to English, is:

> Yes, of course, it's possible.

In both languages you can interpret tons of different meanings into such a simple sentence, if you just want to. What really should be interpreted into it, strongly depends on the context, i.e. on the loudness of the answer, the stress on specific words, the melody of speech, or the overall pitch of the voice. But all of those aspects are results of even more complicates parameters like the kind of your relationship, the mood of the person giving the answer, and on many different other things.

But we, who try to give answers here on this board, we don't know any of those parameters. So it's up to you to find a good interpretation.

Comment: Agree. Furthermore, I suspect this was said in the context of potential dating. In such context it is impossible for us to judge, whether the sentence reflects „agreeing, but not being overjoyed“, or a general coolness/casualness/shyness. I would say, all that matters is: it’s a „yes“! ;)

Comment: I agree with Hubert: without hearing the person while speaking, there are a lot of possible interpretations. The most natural would seem to me something like "why not"

Answer (score 4):

"kann man machen" has a neutral or not very enthusiastic connotation in German. It is ok but it is probably not the best option. Someone who uses it normally thinks of something better or expects a better solution. In a friendship relation you usually ask then: You have a better idea? Hast du eine bessere Idee? In a business relation you take it as a base approach to work further on, or you should seek even further to find better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> Ja klar, kann man machen.

Die Antwort drückt Ambivalenz aus.

"Ja klar" klingt nach spontaner Zustimmung, fast Begeisterung. "Kann man machen" dagegen drückt Indifferenz aus. Jetzt ist es nur noch eine Option. 
Hinzu kommt, dass ohne ersichtlichen Grund vom "Du mit mir" zu einem unpersönlichen "man" gewechselt wird.

Ein "Ja klar, mit Dir würde ich alles machen!" wäre eine klare Zustimmung, insbesondere zu Dir als Person.

Ein "Ja klar, ich gehe so gerne ins Kino!" wäre eine klare Zustimmung zum Kino.

Es hängt natürlich sehr vom Kontext ab, ob zuvor schon was gesagt wurde und was, und was die Personen schon voneinander wissen und wovon sie wissen, dass der andere weiß, dass sie es wissen. Außerdem spielt das Temperament eine Rolle. Womöglich war die Person über ihren ersten, offen geäußerten Enthusiasmus erschrocken und hat schüchtern etwas nachgeschoben, um den Eindruck zu vernebeln.

Stimme, Mimik, Gestik spielen natürlich eine wichtige Rolle, sowie Zeugen, zu denen die zwei Akteure in Beziehung stehen.

Comment: Zeugen? Was sollen die damit zu tun haben?

Comment: @tofro ich stimme unknown zu, daß es durchaus einen Unterschied machen kann, ob meine Schwester sieht, wie ich etwa dem Date zustimme! ;)